# JS: How to get err.code? In my code it is always undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, undefined, error-code

I'm trying to get the error code when I catch an error, but it's always `undefined`.

How do I get the error code?

Here are two examples:

```
try {
  const f = 4;
  f = 9;
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err.code);
  console.log(err.message);
}


try {
  d = 12;
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err.code);
  console.log(err.message);
}
```

Console:

```
undefined
Assignment to constant variable.
undefined 
d is not defined
```

I work on `Node.js v14.17.1`.

Comment: did you try to log just `err`?

Comment: Console.log(err) ?

Comment: What is `err.code` supposed to be? It’s not part of the specification. Wherever you’ve seen `err.code` is likely not a standard implementation.

Comment: Maybe you want `err.name`?

Comment: According to this [link](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errorcode) it should give the identification of the error.

Comment: Maybe `code.name` will suffice for me but in this [link](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errorcode) I realized that `err.code` is more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

As the others commented try console.log(err) to see what the object looks like before trying to select properties from it.

I misunderstood the question with my original answer. To my understanding there is no .code property on the error object returned within a try catch block. Check out this documentation https://javascript.info/try-catch#error-object and try error.name.

Comment: I want a node error not of http.
There should be an error code according to [link](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errorcode) but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

A standard Javascript/Ecmascript error has no `code` property. See the [Error docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/error) for details.

The link you provide, from Node's [Errors documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errorcode) pertains only to custom errors thrown by Node.js — Javascript errors thrown by, say, V8 will adhere to Javascript standard referenced in the 1st link above.